# How to save data with Django ckeditor in database using normal forms?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-ckeditor

I am working with custom form application and I want to integrate ckeditor into it. It works perfectly fine in Django Admin forms but does not work in normal forms.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Post(models.Model):
    text = RichTextField()

    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.text
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns(
    'editor.views',
    url(r'^$', 'home'),
    url(r'^create_post/$', 'create_post'),
    url(r'^delete_post/$', 'delete_post'),
)
```

views.py

```
def home(req):

    tmpl_vars = {
        'all_posts': Post.objects.reverse(),
        'form': PostForm()
    }
    return render(req, 'editor/index.html', tmpl_vars)

def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_text = request.POST.get('the_post')
        response_data = {}
        post = Post(text=post_text, author=request.user)
        post.save()
        post_form = Post()

        response_data['result'] = 'Create post successful!'
        response_data['postpk'] = post.pk
        response_data['text'] = post.text
        response_data['created'] = post.created.strftime('%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p')

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )

    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(widget = CKEditorWidget())
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

index.html

```
<form method="POST" id="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div id="the_post">
            {{ form.media }}
            {{ form.as_p }}
        </div>
        <div id="results"></div>
        <button type="submit">{% trans 'Submit' %}</button>
 </form>
```

In django admin data is saving with ckeditor, while using ckeditor in custom form data is not saving in database. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `RichTextField` field is called `text` So when you checking for `post` data, you should be checking for 'text` input:

```
post_text = request.POST.get('text', '')
```

Also I would process the form like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # Bind data from request.POST into a PostForm
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    # If data is valid, proceeds to create a new post
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.save()

        response = {
            'msg': 'Create post successful!'
            'id': post.pk,
            'text': post.text,
            'created': post.created.strftime('%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p')
        }
```

As for saving the current user as `author`. I would exclude the field from your model. And update the `author` in your view:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    [...]

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ('author',)
```

Comment: Using ModelForm is the best approach, providing the simplest way to accomplish this. This should be marked as Accepted Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have done like this. And it is working for me.

forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        # exclude = ['author', 'updated', 'created', ]
        fields = ['text']
        widgets = {
            'text': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'id': 'post-text', 'required': True, 'placeholder': 'Say something...'}
            ),
        }
```

views.py:

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_text = request.POST.get('the_post')
        response_data = {}

        post = Post(text=post_text, author=request.user)
        post.save()

        response_data['result'] = 'Create post successful!'
        response_data['postpk'] = post.pk
        response_data['text'] = post.text
        response_data['created'] = post.created.strftime('%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p')
        response_data['author'] = post.author.username

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

index.html:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <form method="POST" id="post-form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div id="the_post">
                {{ form.text }}
            </div>
            <div id="results"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="Post">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```